# Unable to insert into database using LINQ-SQL console application

Tags: c#, sql, linq, insert

I am trying to insert it into the database via `LINQ-SQL`. I am trying the following

```
 using(DataContext obj = new DataContext())
        {
            mdc_meters_data data = new mdc_meters_data();
            data.cust_id = cust_id;
            data.device_id = Convert.ToString(device_id);
            data.kwh = Convert.ToString(e_val);
            data.voltage_p1 = Convert.ToString(a_vol_val);
            data.voltage_p2 = Convert.ToString(b_vol_val);
            data.voltage_p2 = Convert.ToString(c_vol_val);
            data.current_p1 = Convert.ToString(a_curr_val);
            data.current_p2 = Convert.ToString(b_curr_val);
            data.current_p3 = Convert.ToString(c_curr_val);
            data.data_date_time = Convert.ToDateTime(theDate.ToString(format));
            data.d_type = Convert.ToString(d_type);
            data.pf1 = Convert.ToString(a_pf_val);
            data.pf2 = Convert.ToString(b_pf_val);
            data.pf3 = Convert.ToString(c_pf_val);
            data.p_id = p_id;
            // executes the commands to implement the changes to the database
            obj.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

The error I am getting is

> 'DataContext' does not contain a definition for 'SubmitChanges' and no accessible extension method 'SubmitChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'DataContext' could be found

**Update 1**

I was doing it wrong so I tried to do it with my class which inherits `DbContext` class. But for an unknown reason, it's still not inserting the data

```
using(mdc_dbEntities obj = new mdc_dbEntities())
        {
            mdc_meters_data data = new mdc_meters_data();
            data.cust_id = cust_id;
            data.device_id = Convert.ToString(device_id);
            data.kwh = Convert.ToString(e_val);
            data.voltage_p1 = Convert.ToString(a_vol_val);
            data.voltage_p2 = Convert.ToString(b_vol_val);
            data.voltage_p2 = Convert.ToString(c_vol_val);
            data.current_p1 = Convert.ToString(a_curr_val);
            data.current_p2 = Convert.ToString(b_curr_val);
            data.current_p3 = Convert.ToString(c_curr_val);
            data.data_date_time = Convert.ToDateTime(theDate.ToString(format));
            data.d_type = Convert.ToString(d_type);
            data.pf1 = Convert.ToString(a_pf_val);
            data.pf2 = Convert.ToString(b_pf_val);
            data.pf3 = Convert.ToString(c_pf_val);
            data.p_id = p_id;
            // executes the commands to implement the changes to the database
            obj.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any LINQ here... Are you sure you posted code that relates to the question? Or maybe you've used "LINQ" as something different? Please [edit] post to clarify.

Comment: Do you mean `obj.SaveChanges()`?!

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour even `SaveChanges()` is not appearing

Comment: You have to install EntityFramework via Nuget and also create class that inherits DbContext

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour it's already installed. The database that I am inserting is `MySQL`

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour There is already a class which is inserting `DbContext`

Comment: But you used `DataContext` in `using` clause. you have to use class which inherits `DataContext` instead

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Please check my update 1

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour Yes i was doing it wrong I corrected it but still it's not saving the data. Please see my `update 1`

Comment: You don't add anything to `obj`.